# Adobe reader and terminal

Tags: 14.04, adobe-reader

i want to open Adobe Reader via terminal and pass some pdf files'  absolute paths to it to open them 
like for instance for virtualbox in terminal u can write that to start VM "`virtualbox --startvm VMname`" 
Does anyone know how to do it like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start Adobe Reader from terminal

- `cd` to the directory where you have installed the Adobe Reader. If
  you have not provided the installation path durring installtion then
  it should be `/opt/Adobe`.
- Now `cd` into Reader/bin folder.
  For me it is like 
    `cd /opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin/` (I have combine both step in one `cd` command)
- Now run the `acroread` file followed by your PDF file you want to open.

  `./acroread ~/test.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

If Adobe reader is your default pdf reader is Adobe Reader then you can simply run `xdg-open /path/to/filename`. BTW this works on any file, not only pdf; xdg-open means "open with default application".

If it is not your default pdf reader and want it to be so, find any pdf file in Nautilus (The "Files" app) right-click and choose **Properties**. The choose the **Open with** tab, select Adobe Reader and click **Set as default**.

Comment: How to make it my default  pdf reader?

Comment: See modified answer

Comment: adobe is not even exist in this list u talk about so i can't set it